# Issue regarding Open Graph protocol in discord and crawlers

Tags: html, embed, share-open-graph

I have a problem on my site with ogp not showing up in discord or ogp check crawlers (i.e.rakko) but showing up properly in opengraphcheck (https://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcorepunk.org.pl)
Also works in facebook attachments/sharing debugger and shows up normally

site: https://corepunk.org.pl/

Also, I'm aware that htaccess redirects may be at fault here so also posting them here.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="CorePunk PL" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Strona społeczności CorepunkPL, która stara się łączyć graczy o podobnych zainteresowaniach oraz publikować wiadomości związane z grą Corepunk w języku polskim." />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://corepunk.org.pl" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="pl_PL" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="CorepunkPL" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://corepunk.org.pl/_img/ikonka.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="512" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="427" />
    <meta property="og:image:alt" content="Logo CorepunkPL" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

Would be interesting to get any suggestions why this is not working, thanks in advance for any answers :)